# Need to do collaborative editing of multi-node project with ownership of data and simple setup/workflow

Tags: google-docs, wiki, collaboration

I have a project to collaboratively create some content (RPG worldbuilding). Ideally that would be a multi-page setup (wiki or tree-based outline with individual docs) with the pages having formatted text and pictures. It would be possible to just have one giant doc with a good outline but it would not be preferred. I have tried a wiki. I have looked at Nuclino (which has a data model that comes closest to what I want). I have looked at the crunch-it-all-together-option of using google docs.

However they all have some drawbacks that I would like to avoid and I am at a loss atm of how to best solve that.

1. A wiki requires more technical knowledge than some of the people involved have.
2. I really, really need ownership of the data in a usable form. The wiki we were using and Nuclino for example misses an export function. I can't rely on some wiki hosting being there in the future or some company like Nuclino not going bankrupt, I need the data on my machine in a usable format.
3. I would like to avoid creating a single document of monstrous size like in google docs.
4. I don't have the time or motivation at the moment for a solution that requires an overly very technical setup

How would you go about solving this? Any recommendations? At the moment I'm leaning to the single monster doc but all of the things I've looked at are not ideal.

Comment: Are you still looking? What do mean by "need the data on my machine in an usable form"? How many people will be collaborating on this?

Comment: Still looking. ~5 people maybe. "Need data on my machines" means I cannot rely on some random service to not go out of business for access to the data.